# Exceptions while downloading files from url using java

Tags: java, ssl

I have the following java code which downloads files from https urls

```
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) sourceURL
                    .openConnection();
            httpcon.setRequestProperty(
                    "User-Agent",
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");

            in = httpcon.getInputStream();
            out = new FileOutputStream(target);

            OtherUtils.bufStreamCopy(in, out, 64);

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            debugMsg("FAIL: IO Exception caught.");
            if (out == null)
                debugMsg("out = null.");
            if (in == null)
                debugMsg("in == null");
            throw new IOException(ioe.getMessage());
        }
```

I am able download files successfully using above code on some of the machines.
But on some machines it throws exceptions like

**Remote host closed connection during handshake**

**java.net.SocketException: Connection reset**

**java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe**

These exceptions are thrown while getting the inputstream

```
in = httpcon.getInputStream();
```

What is the problem with my code that causes above exceptions, Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

NO PROBLEM WITH YOUR CODE

It's not the problem of your machine because

> Remote host closed connection during handshake

will happen when the server you are connected to, closes the connection.

And morever read about `TCP handshake` : http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml

A reset flag will have to be sent when you as the client only directly send **ACK** without first **SYN**cing with server.

Here is a quick one: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_AamnZyf3C_A/TBvQXqrnqII/AAAAAAAAAY0/lf0Kndz8N8A/s1600/tcp+3+way+handshake.png

Comment: So How do I make sure that this code works on all machines. how do I fix this ?

Comment: It depends on server, if it doesn't respond well... Then it's your bad luck out code a better service